# Short-lived objects

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

What is the overhead of generating a lot of temporary objects (i.e. for interim results) that "die young" (never promoted to the next generation during a garbage collection interval)?  I'm assuming that the "new" operation is very cheap, as it is really just a pointer increment.  However, what are the hidden costs of dealing with this temporary "litter"?

Comment: If you really have simple objects, and especially if they're easy to reset, create an object pool and reuse them. This can work for complicated objects too. Once I had an app that made thousands of small bitmaps for drawing interem text that couldn't be drawn directly on a page for logic reasons. For 1000s of pgs, sizes were reused. Instead of 'dispose,' I stored them in a 'free' hash table with the key being WidthxHeight (pointed to a list of the bitmaps) and checked it before doing NEW. If there, remove it, put it in use. Sounds expensive, but making bitmaps must be worse. Huge speedup.

Comment: @FastAl I assume you mean something like [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which “Encapsulates a GDI+ bitmap” implying [something like a syscal to create/destroy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) them. That’s quite different from pure .net objects which I assume the OP is asking about.

Comment: @binki - You are right about the bitmap, it's much more expense of course than plain objects. But if the loop is tight enough and you aren't doing much with the objects ... speed increases might still be worth reusing them. GC still has to eventually do something. Of course in that case, it depends. He doesn't mention the size, bitmaps can be temporary and as you mention there is quite a hidden cost to them.  New objects, if large, might be cleared before use too, if your code overwrites what's there anyway it could mean a 2x speedup (That's kind of ninja tho).

Comment: @FastAl - I would modify your answer to say that an object pool makes sense if (a) it is expensive to create or destroy the objects, and (b) your app is likely to need a similar quantity of those objects again soon. The definition of "expensive" in (a) is that profiling shows that a substantial fraction of your total time is spent in creating/destroying the objects. Otherwise, why bother?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve spot on steve, these are all prerequisites 'in my head' that I didn't think to say. My original comment isn't editable anymore.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not a lot - the garbage collector is very fast for gen0. It also tunes itself, adjusting the size of gen0 depending on how much it manages to collect each time it goes. (If it's managed to collect a lot, it will reduce the size of gen0 to collect earlier next time, and vice versa.)

The ultimate test is how *your* application performs though. Perfmon is very handy here, showing how much time has been spent in GC, how many collections there have been of each generation etc.

Comment: Downvoters: comments are welcome, otherwise no-one (including me) will know what you disagree with about my answer...

Comment: It's almost certainly installed on your Windows box already. Hit Windows-R and just type "perfmon". Otherwise finding it will depend on which version of Windows you're using.

Comment: I had no idea you could use the performance monitor to monitor garbage collection.  That could be useful.

Comment: There are vast numbers of perf counters for .NET. It's really impressive.

Comment: If anybody is still readnig this ;-) you can always get even more details with CLR profiler - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43220090/tracking-down-a-net-windows-service-memory-leak/43620759#43620759 very useful and cool for optimization.

Answer (score 4):

As you say the allocation itself is very inexpensive. The cost of generating lots of short lived objects is more frequent garbage collections as they are triggered when generation 0's budget is exhausted. However, a generation 0 collection is fairly cheap, so as long as your object really are short lived the overhead is most likely not significant.

On the other hand the common example of concatenating lots of strings in a loop pushes the garbage collector significantly, so it all depends on the number of objects you create. It doesn't hurt to think about allocation.

The cost of garbage collection is that managed threads are suspended during compaction.

Comment: IMHO, you have the most important line in any answer here: "*The cost of generating lots of .. objects is more frequent garbage collections*...". **Why** this is important is because it isn't just the objects being created by the code one is writing at the moment. If an earlier GC causes objects from **anywhere** in your code to survive Gen0, that would have died in Gen0 if there was a bit longer time between collections, this could potentially be a substantial cost.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this isn't something you should probably be worrying about and sounds like it starts to fall very close to "micro-optimization". The GC was designed with an assumption that a "well tuned application" will have all of it's allocations in Gen0 - meaning that they all "die young". Any time you allocate a new object it is always in Gen0. A collection won't occur until the Gen0 threshold is passed and there isn't enough available space in Gen0 to hold the next allocation.

The "new" operation is actually a bunch of things:

1. allocating memory
2. running the types constructor
3. returning a pointer to the memory
4. incrementing the next object pointer

Answer (score 1):

Although the new operation is designed and written efficiently it is not free and does take time to allocate new memory. The memory allocation library needs to track what chunks are available for allocation and the newly allocated memory is zeroed.

Creating a lot of objects that die young will also trigger garbage collection more often and that operation can be expensive. Especially with "stop the world" garbage collectors.

Here's an article from the MSDN on how it works:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx

Note: that it describes how calling garbage collection is expensive because it needs to build the object graph before it can start garbage collection.

Comment: From the linked article: "These tests also show that it takes less than 1 millisecond on a 200Mhz Pentium to perform a full GC of generation 0. It is Microsoft's goal to make GCs take no more time than an ordinary page fault." Hardly "very expensive" IMO. Not free, certainly, but if (cont.)

Comment: the code is more readable with lots of small, short-lived objects then I'd rather go that way until it was *proven* to be a bottle-neck than bend my design out of shape to counteract a performance "problem" which may not be a problem at all.

Comment: I agree and I'm not saying that they should change how they write programs. The question asked what the underlying overheads are, and I tried to provide an answer.

Comment: I also changes the comment about "very expensive" so it's not as strong. 1ms on a 200mhz chip is still hundreds of thousands of cycles and with the current memory wall problem GC on modern computers takes millions of CPU cycles.

Comment: Millions even for *just* a gen0 collection? That sounds like more than I'd expect. I'd be interested to read more though - do you have any references?

Comment: Here's a classic survey:
PR Wilson, Uniprocessor garbage collection techniques, International Workshop on Memory Management. 

The paper surveys many GC algorithms and notes that GC typically adds an additional 5 - 20% runtime and 40 - 280% space overhead.

Comment: Here's another more recent article:
http://www.cis.udel.edu/~cavazos/ismm-07.pdf

"GC has a significant effect on overall execution time ... In the most extreme case, one configuration ... spent 89% of its execution time performing GC. The mean proportion of execution time spent in
GC is 12.2% ..."

Comment: Yes, but here we are talking about Gen 0, not about GC in general

Answer (score 0):

If these objects are never promoted out of Generation 0 then you will see pretty good performance.  The only hidden cost I can see is that if you exceed your Generation 0 budget you will force the GC to compact the heap but the GC will self-tune so this isn't much of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is generational in .Net.  Short lived objects will collect first and frequently.  Gen 0 collection is cheap, but depending on the scale of the number of objects you're creating, it could be quite costly.  I'd run a profiler to find out if it is affecting performance.  If it is, consider switching them to structs. These do not need to be collected.