# Tracking Down a .NET Windows Service Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks

Before installing my windows service in production, I was looking for reliable tests that I can perform to make sure my code doesn't contain memory leaks.
However, All what I can find on the net was using task manager to look at used memory or some paid memory profiler tools.

From my understanding, looking at the task manager is not really helpful and cannot confirm the memory leakage (in case, there is).

1. **How to confirm whether there is a memory leak or not?**
2. Is there any free tools to find the source of memory leaks?

Note: I'm using .Net Framework 4.6 and Visual Studio 2015 Community

Comment: It all depends on what exactly your service does.

Comment: @Evk Regardless what the service does, How can I make sure there is no memory leak in a service?

Comment: I mean it is hard to really test program for memory leaks, especially windows service. You have to actually use it, extensively, over time for some period. Growing memory is not indication of leak by itself, because GC might decide to not collect anything if there is no reason to (no memory pressure). So best you can do is write good code without leaks and also monitor memory usage of application over time, collect memory dumps if memory reached some threshold and analyze them with profiler.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well you can use task manager.
GC apps can leak memory, and it will show there.

But...

## Free tool - ".Net CLR profiler"

There is a free tool, and it's from Microsoft, and it's awesome. This is a must-use for all programs that leak references. Search MS' site.

Leaking references means you forget to set object references to null, or they never leave scope, and this is almost as likely to occur in Garbage collected languages as not - lists building up and not clearing, event handlers pointing to delegates, etc.

It's the GC equivalent of memory leaks and has the same result. This program tells you what references are taking up tons of memory - and you will know if it's supposed to be that way or not, and if not, you can go find them and fix the problem!

It even has a cool visualization of what objects allocate what memory (so you can track down mistakes). I believe there are youtubes of this if you need an explanation.

[image: Memory Usage Visualization]

[Wikipedia page with download links...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLR_Profiler)

NOTE: You will likely have to run your app *not* as a service to use this. It starts first and then runs your app. You can do this with TopShelf or by just putting the guts in a dll that runs from an EXE that implments the service integrations (service host pattern).

Answer (score 3):

Although managed code implies no direct memory management, you still have to manage your instances. Those instances 'claim' memory. And it is all about the usage of these instances, keeping them alive when you don't expect them to be.

Just one of many examples: wrong usage of disposable classes can result in a lot of instances claiming memory. For a windows service, a slow but steady increase of instances can eventually result in to much memory usage.

**Yes, there is a tool to analyze memory leaks.** It just isn't free. However you might be able to identify your problem within the 7 day trial.

I would suggest to take a loot at the [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/).

It is great to analyze memory leaks during development. It uses the concept of snapshots to compare new instances, disposed instances etc. This is a great help to understand how your service uses its memory. You can then dig deeper into why new instances get created or are kept alive.

**Yes, you can test to confirm whether memory leaks are introduced.**
However, just out-of-the box this will not be very useful. This is because no one can anticipate what will happen during runtime. The tool can analyze your app for common issues, but this is not guaranteed.

However, you *can* use this tool to integrate memory consumption into your unit test framework like `NUnit` or `MSTest`.

Answer (score 2):

Of course a memory profiler is the first kind of tool to try, but it will only tell you whether your instances keep increasing.  You still want to know whether it is normal that they are increasing.  Also, once you have established that some instances keep increasing for no good reason, (meaning, you have a leak,) you will want to know precisely which call trees lead to their allocation, so that you can troubleshoot the code that allocates them and fix it so that it does eventually release them.

Here is some of the knowledge I have collected over the years in dealing with such issues:

1. Test your service as a regular executable as much as possible.  Trying to test the service as an actual service just makes things too complicated.
2. Get in the habit of explicitly undoing everything that you do at the end of the scope of that thing which you are doing. For example, if you register an observer to the event of some observee, there should should always be some point in time (the disposal of the observer or the observee?) that you de-register it.  In theory, garbage collection should take care of that by collecting the entire graph of interconnected observers and observees, but in practice, if you don't kick the habit of forgetting to undo things that you do, you get memory leaks.
3. Use `IDisposable` as much as possible, and make your destructors report if someone forgot to invoke `Dispose()`.  More about this method here: [Mandatory disposal vs. the "Dispose-disposing" abomination](http://blog.michael.gr/2015/03/on-dispose-bool-disposing-abomination.html) Disclosure: I am the author of that article.
4. Have regular checkpoints in your program where you release everything that should be releasable (as if the program is performing an orderly shutdown in order to terminate) and then force a garbage collection to see whether you have any leaks.
5. If instances of some class appear to be leaking, use the following trick to discover the precise calling tree that caused their allocation: within the constructor of that class, allocate an exception object without throwing it, obtain the stack trace of the exception, and store it.  If you discover later that this object has been leaked, you have the necessary stack trace.  Just don't do this with too many objects, because allocating an exception and obtaining the stack trace from it is ridiculously slow, only Microsoft knows why.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the free Memoscope memory profiler

https://github.com/fremag/MemoScope.Net

I do not agree that you can trust the Task Manager to check if you have a memory leak or not. The problem with a garbage collector is that it can decide based on heuristics to keep the memory after a memory spike and do not return it to the OS. You might have a 2 GB Commit size but 90% of them can be free.

You should use [VMMAP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/vmmap.aspx) to check during the tests what type of memory your process contains. You do not only have the managed heap, but also unmanaged heap, private bytes, stacks (thread leaks), shared files and much more which need to be tracked.

VMMap has also command line interface which makes it possible to create snapshots at regular intervals which you can examine later. If you have a memory growth you can find out which type of memory is leaked which needs depending on the leak type different debugging tooling approaches.

Answer (score 0):

I would not say that the Garbage collector is infallible.  There are times when it fails unknowingly and they are not so straight forward.  Memory streams are a common cause of memory leaks.  You can open them in one context and they may never even get closed, even though the usage is wrapped in a using statement (the definition of a disposable object that should be cleaned up immediately after its usage falls out of scope).  If you are experiencing crashes due to running out of memory, Windows does create dump files that you can sift through.

[enter link description here](http://MSDN%20dump%20files)

This is by no means fun or easy and is quite tedious but it tends to be your best bet.

Common areas that are easy to create memory leaks are anything that is using the System.Drawing dll, memory streams, and if you are doing some serious multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework and a DI pattern, perhaps using Castle Windsor, you can easily get memory leaks.

The main thing to do is use the using(  ){ } statement where-ever you can to automatically mark objects as disposed.

Also, you want to turn off automatic tracking on Entity Framework where you are only reading and not writing. Best to isolate your writes, use a using() {} at this point, get a dbContext (with tracking on), write your data.

If you want to investigate what is on the heap. The best tool I've used is RedGate ANTS http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/solving-memory-problems/getting-started   not cheap but it works.

However, by using the using() {} pattern where-ever you can (don't make a static or singleton DbContext and never have one context in a massive loop of updates, dispose of them as often as you can!) then you find memory isn't often an issue.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you're dealing with unmanaged code, i would be so bold to say you don't have to worry about **memory leaks**. Any unreferenced object in managed code will be removed by the garbage collector, and the possibility in finding a memory leak within the .net framework i would say you should be considered very lucky (well, unlucky). You don't have to worry about memory leak.

However, you can still encounter ever-growing memory usage, if references to objects are never released. For example, say you keep an internal log structure, and you just keep adding entries to a log list. Then every entry still have references from the log list and therefore will never be collected.

From my experience, you can definitely use the task manager as an indicator whether your system has growing issues; if the memory usage steadily keep rising, you know you have an issue. If it grows to a point but eventually converges to a certain size, it indicates it has reached its operating threshold.

If you want a more detailed view of managed memory usage, you can download the process explorer [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx), developed by Microsoft. It is still quite blunt, but it gives a somewhat better statistical view than task manager.

Comment: This is a good answer. It answers your first question: you can use Task Manager to observe the memory usage behaviour. If memory usage never drops this indicates you have a problem. From my experience this works well. No need for other tools. The key thing is that the garbage collector only removes unreferenced objects, so make sure that all references to objects are destroyed when done. Implement the Dispose pattern throughout your service. Call Dispose whenever available and set large objects to null. This is the best way to prevent memory problems.

Comment: @Micael That's not true. Memory leaks can be caused by managed code too. Think of not disposed objects, delegate subscription, weak references...

Comment: Not disposed objects will eventually be disposed by the garbage collector. I guess it come down to definition. Memory leaks usually refers to pieces of memory not being freed, but nothing refers to it. Chaining chunks of memory where each chunk references another is not considered a memory leak, but rather an inefficient structure; you wouldn't want the garbage collector to free the memory, since you might actually have a reason to keep it that way. It's a memory eater, but it's not a memory leak.